# Child ViewController's view is nil when trying to add it to a View Container

Tags: ios, swift

I have two view controllers. The parent view controller has a view container that I'm trying to display the child view controller inside it. Here is my code:

Parent View Controller:

```
class ParentViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var viewContainer: UIView! //View Container inside Parent View Controller


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let childVc = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChildViewControllerStoryId") as! ChildViewController

        addChild(childVc)
        childVc.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        viewContainer.addSubview(childVc.view)
        childVc.didMove(toParent: self)

    }
}
```

Child View Controller:

```
class ChildViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var textLabel: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        textLabel.text = "random text"
    }
}
```

I'm getting this error at "viewContainer.addSubview(childVc.view)" :

> Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an
>   Optional value: file /../../.swift

I think it's telling me that the view of the child view controller is nil. What seems to be the problem here?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, this is embarrassing. I guess my xcode bugged or something, but I tried removing the container view and adding it again and making a new outlet, and it worked! I don't know what happened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen if your ChildViewController does not properly have its class set in Interface Builder. Make sure it is, and comment back if that does not fix it.

Comment: I doubled checked and everything is set properly.

Comment: Well, this is embarrassing. I guess my xcode bugged or something, but I tried removing the container view and adding it again and making a new outlet, and it worked! I don't know what happened